# using Jquery to append html elements in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii2, widget

I want to append a slider to the card

```
 $slider10= "\kriss\swiper\SwiperWidget::widget([
                        'slides' => [
                            $slide1,
                            $slide2,
                        ],
                        'pagination' => false,
                        'navigation' => false,
                        'scrollbar' => false,
                        'clientOptions' => [
                            'speed' => 200,
                            'loop' => false,
                        ]
                    ]); ";
```

slide 1 is as follows:

```
    $slide1 = '
                <div class="row stamps-div" id="slide1"> 

                    <div>

                        <div >
                            <i class="fas fa-plus" ></i>  
                           .
                           .
                           .                     
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> ';
```

I used jquery to append it to the card but I am getting syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
$script = "
        $(function() {
            $('#num').change(function(){

                var value = $('#num option:selected').val();

                alert('".$slider10 ."');
                var x = '".$slider10."';
                if(value <= 10){
                    console.log(x);
                    $('#card').append(x);
                }

            });
        });";

$this->registerJs($script, yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

Comment: you need to excape single quotes in slider10 when you embed it into code here: ```var x = '".$slider10."';```

Comment: i cant have an idea what the javascript part of the code is related with ?what is `#num` to which you have the change event, and you are saving the output of the slider widget to a variable `$slider10` and then trying to alert it ? why? it will never work the way you are doing it as the line break will raise an exception not only at the `alert()` but the `var x` too where you are trying to initialize it as you cannot have a line break in the var's value and formatting the custom html for the slides wont work as the html of the widget is also appended which you cant edit.

Comment: you can switch to the string literals if you like `\`` but you would need to include babel.js to make it work in IE

Answer (score 0):

In javascript string you can not use `new line` it string known as multi string. to use it you have 2 way.

1: remove new lines with `php` like this:

```
 $slide1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $slide1);
```

2: Or add `+` every line like this in `js`:

```
$slide1 = '<div class="row stamps-div" id="slide1">'+
    '<div>'+
        '<div >'+
            '<i class="fas fa-plus" ></i>'+
            '.'+
            '.'+
            '.'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div> ';
```

then use it in script code.

Comment: I tried this solution before and it still shows an error <Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token> although the source in the dev tool is showing the html content.

Comment: @Zainab You opened `php tag` in your question. you cant run php function in string. and that is the first problem in your code. first check it and if your problem still alive. you must edit you question.

Comment: this wont work as the line breaks are appended from the widget html to not just the custom html for the slide.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I think you have misunderstood with my answer. The question problem is in `js multi line string`, must remove new lines

Comment: no i havent, the problem is in `js` and that wont fix by removing line breaks from the slide html only ,